# window size sometimes changed while rotating the surface

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, screen-rotation

System: Microsoft Surface, Windows 8.1 (Not Win RT)

When I start the Application and activate the keyboard, it looks like this in

portrait:
[image]

landscape:
[image]

As you can see the keyboard fits and the window size is maximized. When I continue to rotate the surface multiple times, I sometimes get this:
[image]

The window is not maximized any longer. This can only be fixed by manually maximize the window again. Any Idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: I have a Surface 2. Judging by how poorly the screen updates when rotating the unit, I wouldn't be surprised if that was just the Surface telling the app that it is still in landscape mode. I can lay my Surface on its side and sometimes it doesn't update at all.

Comment: I tested it again with a completly naked WPF application - Just a blank window. Even on this application the above behavior exists.

Comment: Exactly... it's *not* the WPF application... it's the crappy Surface.

Comment: But it does not appear for the explorer window for example. So this behavior does not exist for all windows, but WPF Windows (and maybe others too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by my own in the meantime. I added an event handler to `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanging`

Doing a short Thread.Sleep on UI Thread. The issue occures because the keyboard flip reacts faster then my own application. I know it's a workaround but the sleep is just 200 ms and it works like charm